# simple C++ comparision if statement

Tags: c++, c, if-statement, for-loop

I have a function in C++ that takes a char array  thingArray[6] and places ' ' onto each place.

like:

```
   for (int i =0; i<5; i++)
   {
       thingArray[i] = ' ';
   }
```

now I have another function that sticks a character if it finds an empty space in the array.  please say the array now looks like: 'w',' ','R','E',' ','E',

if I do:

```
for (int i = 0;i<5;i++)
{
     if (thingArray[i] == ' ')
     {
         thingArray[i] = 'M';
     }
}
```

It should be pretty intuitive that the for loop will traverse the array and find the ' '  and stick an 'M' in it's place.  Sometimes it will not work.  This is my first time coding in a language that uses pointers so I think that may be one of my issues.

Any suggestions, or a better way of doing this would be great!

Thanks.

Comment: How have you defined `thingArray`?

Comment: Can you post *all* of your code? You might have an error elsewhere.

Comment: Does your array contain blank spaces or empty characters, i.e. `' '` vs `''`?

Comment: You definitely need to show more code

Comment: Assuming you've already declared `thingArray` with `char* thingArray = new char[5]` or `char thingArray[5]`, this code snippet should work just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `thingArray` is a string literal, then it's actually constant and you can't change the value of its elements.